# ruby /rails undefined method `DAYNAMES' for Date:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

my code:

```
<% require 'date' %>
 <% today = Date.today%>
 <% (today..(today+7)).each{ |day| %>
 <a href="#" class="btn btn-large btn-primary disabled"><%=Date::DAYNAMES(day.wday)%> </a>
 <% } %>
```

I got error message

```
undefined method `DAYNAMES' for Date:Class
```

What is missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Date::DAYNAMES` is an array, not a method.  From [the docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html):

> DAYNAMES An array of string of full name of days of the week in
>   English. The first is “Sunday”.

So, you'd want to do:

```
<% require 'date' %>
 <% today = Date.today%>
 <% (today..(today+7)).each{ |day| %>
 <a href="#" class="btn btn-large btn-primary disabled"><%=Date::DAYNAMES[day.wday]%> </a>
 <% } %>
```

**NOTICE**: The brackets instead of the parenthesis in your link.

Answer (score 1):

`Date::DAYNAMES` is an array, not a method. Try this:

```
Date::DAYNAMES[day.wday]
```